# Python - Move to the next list element if condition is FALSE

Tags: python, list, loops

So i have the following list: `list = [['apples','bananas'],['watermelons','melons']]`

I want to check if each separate word in the nested lists match to a bigger list of words called `wordlist`, and only if both words match the program will be able to continue.

```
wordlist = ['bananas','strawberys','appricots','melons','watermelons]
```

So I wrote this:

```
for i in range(len(wordlist)):
    occur_all = True
    for word in list:
        if word in wordlist[i]:
            occur = True
        else:
            occur = False
        occur_all = occur_all and occur
    if occur_all == True:
       print('words in list')
```

So unless all words belong in `wordlist` the program will not move on.

What I want to do is if first word that is checked, eg. `apples`, does not belong in wordlist, I want to move to the next `i` without checking `bananas` in order to make my program faster.
Is that an efficient way to do that?

Comment: You can [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) out of the inner loop.

Comment: I think the "or" operator is short-circuiting in Python, for example. Use the or operator then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a good example of a `for` loop with `else` clause. Please note: the indentation is valid, the `else` belongs to the `for` statement.

```
llw = [['apples','bananas'],['watermelons','melons']]
wordlist = ['bananas','strawberys','appricots','melons','watermelons']

for item in llw:
    for word in item:
        if word not in wordlist:
            print(f'{word} not in wordlist, skipping list {item}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'{item} was found in wordlist')
```

Out:

```
apples not in wordlist, skipping list ['apples', 'bananas']
['watermelons', 'melons'] was found in wordlist
```